# PromiseKit AnyPromise then crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010

Tags: ios, crash, objective-c-blocks, promisekit

I have a crash in Fabric that points to the first line in Objective-C:

```
somePromise.then(^ {
  // some more code
});
```

The app is using PromiseKit. Why is this crashing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: In some cases `somePromise` might be `nil`. Calling a method on `nil` (or "sending a message to `nil`") in Objective-C should be perfectly fine, though, right?

Well, in this case the code isn't actually trying to send an Objective-C message to `nil`. Instead, it is trying to execute a block that is `nil`. It's like doing this:

```
void (^block)() = nil;
block();  // CRASH!
```

So: make sure the promise is not `nil` before calling `then` on it.

Thanks to @mxcl for giving me the solution here: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/344#issuecomment-167020593